Redis Data Persistence Issue in Azure Container Instance (ACI)
I am working on deploying a Redis instance in Azure Container Instances (ACI) using a custom Docker image, but I am encountering an issue with data persistence. Despite setting up proper volume mounting and configuring Redis for persistence (using the appendonly.aof file), I am still concerned about losing data during container restarts.
Here’s the setup I am using:
Dockerfile:


FROM redis:latest

# Install procps to include sysctl
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y procps && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Add vm.overcommit_memory setting to /etc/sysctl.conf
RUN echo "vm.overcommit_memory=1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf

# Default command to run Redis with sysctl
CMD ["sh", "-c", "ulimit -n 65536 && sysctl -p && redis-server --save '300 1' --appendonly yes --dir /data --appendfilename appendonly.aof --maxmemory 3gb --maxmemory-policy noeviction"]



Terraform Configuration (ACI Deployment):
resource "azurerm_container_group" "example" {
  name                = "redis-db"
  location            = "location"
  resource_group_name = "rg"
  os_type = "Linux"

  container {
    name   = "redis-db"
    image  = "arcregistry.azurecr.io/redis:latest"
    cpu    = "1"
    memory = "6"

    ports {
      port     = 6379
      protocol = "TCP"
    }

    environment_variables = {
      "ENV"              = "prod"
      "REDIS_ULIMIT"     = "65536"
    }

    volume {
      name                = "redis-data"
      mount_path          = "/data"
      share_name          = "redisdata"
      storage_account_name = "storage_account_name"
      storage_account_key  = "storage_key"
    }

    commands = [
    "sh", "-c",
    "chmod -R 775 /data && chown -R redis:redis /data && redis-server --save '300 1' --appendonly yes --dir /data --appendfilename appendonly.aof --rdb-del-sync-files yes --maxmemory 3gb --maxmemory-policy noeviction"
]
  }

  dns_name_label = "redis-db"
  ip_address_type = "Public"
}

Even though I’ve configured Redis to use an append-only file (appendonly.aof) for data persistence and properly mounted an Azure file share to store the Redis data, I am concerned about potential data loss when the container is restarted.

The ACI container has a volume mount configured (/data).
The redis.conf is updated to ensure Redis writes to appendonly.aof.
However, after restarting the container, I still observe that Redis does not seem to restore its data from the appendonly.aof file.

I also encountered the following warning in the Redis logs:
# WARNING Memory overcommit must be enabled! Without it, a background save or replication may fail under low memory condition. Being disabled, it can also cause failures without low memory condition, see https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/issues/1328. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.


Is there something specific to Azure Container Instances that could be preventing data persistence in Redis?

what happens if you create a dummy file in /data ? can you check whether it persists after restart?

Hello, to clarify, the data loss in Redis occurs at random times and is not necessarily tied to container restarts (see picture).
However, after making the suggested test, I was able to find the created file dummy_file.txt in the /data directory, after container restart.
